NTS server setup on new ubuntu servers
To set up NTS on ubuntu servers we followed the instruction as per
https://www.netnod.se/netnod-time/how-to-use-nts
We installed chrony version 4.2 and through port 4460 is establishing connection to nts.netnode.se from my nts server. We started chrony, enable but still it is not picking the nts.netnode.se through chronyc source -v we found it.

Here i am not getting why it is take PHCO as current server for time synchronization and nts.netnode.se is in ^?

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Ubuntu 22.0 version
